# Load JPG,BMP, GIF and PNG using CImage under Windows CE6?

Tags: class, bitmap, load, windows-ce, jpeg

I am trying to load JPG images using CImage under windows CE6. I have searched online but most of them use a function as described below (but the function itself is disabled for CE users):

```
CImage myImage;

myImage.Load(_T("C:\Image.jpg"));// Not available in windows CE
```

Because in **atlimage.h**:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WCE

inline HRESULT CImage::Load( IStream* pStream ) throw()
{
    if( !InitGDIPlus() )
    {
        return( E_FAIL );
    }

    Gdiplus::Bitmap bmSrc( pStream );
    if( bmSrc.GetLastStatus() != Gdiplus::Ok )
    {
        return( E_FAIL );
    }

    return( CreateFromGdiplusBitmap( bmSrc ) );
}

inline HRESULT CImage::Load( LPCTSTR pszFileName ) throw()
{
    if( !InitGDIPlus() )
    {
        return( E_FAIL );
    }

    Gdiplus::Bitmap bmSrc( (CT2W)pszFileName );
    if( bmSrc.GetLastStatus() != Gdiplus::Ok )
    {
        return( E_FAIL );
    }

    return( CreateFromGdiplusBitmap( bmSrc ) );
}
```

Is there any other alternative method of loading jpg/bmp/gif/png files using CImage or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old post, I was looking for this also recently so figured I'd update it.

Windows Ce 6 supports IImagingFactory.  It's a pain in the but to use, but it works, you can load png's or bitmaps from disk or memory.

[Microsoft Documentation for CE 5.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452202.aspx)

[Microsoft Blog example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehall/2008/10/23/ce6-using-imaging-apis-to-loaddisplay-images/)

Answer (score -1):

`CImage::Load` is [definitely supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/tf4bytf8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) under MFC in Windows CE.

Can you clarify what you mean by "disabled for CE users"?

There is no "C" drive in Windows CE, so your example code won't work, but there's no reason something like this shouldn't:

```
CImage myImage;
myImage.Load(_T("\\My Device\\Image.jpg"));
```

Comment: When I declare a new CImage variable and look for member functions under it, it doesn't show me the "Load" function. It just shows me LoadFromResource function.

Comment: I've edited my question to show this.. Have a look.. It may be something is wrong the way I am trying to access it..